# Shell is interpreting IFS=$'\n' as IFS='n'

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

I am using a Bash shell on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, and it seems that IFS=$'\n' is being treated as IFS='n'.

Script in use:

```
concat=$(echo -n "concat:" && find /home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips -name '*.aac' -mtime -1 -exec echo -n "{}|" \;)
echo $concat
IFS=$'\n'
for i in =$(echo "$concat" | sed -e 's/^concat://' -e 's/|$//' -e 's/|/\n/g');
    do rm "$i"
done
```

Output of `$(echo "$concat" | sed -e 's/^concat://' -e 's/|$//' -e 's/|/\n/g')` :

```
rm: cannot remove `=/home/jhvisser/bi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/Streamripper_rips/Safe A': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `d Sou': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `d - Capital Cities (1).aac\n/home/jhvisser/bi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/Streamripper_rips/U Got It Bad - Usher.aac\n/home/jhvisser/bi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/Streamripper_rips/Life Of The Party - PRTY H3RO.aac\n/home/jhvisser/bi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/Streamripper_rips/i': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `complete/True Love - Pi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `k.aac\n/home/jhvisser/bi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/Streamripper_rips/i': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `complete/The Other Side - Jaso': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ` Derulo.aac\n/home/jhvisser/bi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/Streamripper_rips/Karma - Kristi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `a Maria.aac': No such file or directory
```

It is breaking at every 'n'. Check below to see the correct names of all the files:

```
/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/Safe And Sound - Capital Cities (1).aac
/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/U Got It Bad - Usher.aac
/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/Life Of The Party - PRTY H3RO.aac
/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/incomplete/True Love - Pink.aac
/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/incomplete/The Other Side - Jason Derulo.aac
/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/Karma - Kristina Maria.aac
```

I'm wondering why this may be happening? Shouldn't it be breaking at every newline?

For more detail of what is being done check out [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10971/discussion-between-tim-and-fogest).

Comment: How are you invoking the script? Like "./filename" or like "sh ./filename"?

Comment: Also, notice how the output contains the literal characters "\n"? Sed is not replacing pipes with newlines, it's replacing pipes with the 2 chars "\n". Try `-e $'s/|/\n/g'`

Comment: @glennjackman I am using sh.

Comment: @glennjackman replacing `-e 's/|/\n/g'` with `-e $'s/|/\n/g'` still produced the same results.

Comment: well, `sh` is not `bash`. If you need a bash-specific feature like ANSI-C quoting, you have to specifically launch your script with `bash`

Comment: @glennjackman Okay, thanks! That was the issue! Now I just have this problem: `rm: cannot remove `=/home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips/Safe And Sound - Capital Cities (1).aac': No such file or directory`

Comment: You've prefixed the `$(echo $concat)`-block with a `=` -- does that serve any purpose?

Comment: @n.st No, it doesn't. Seems to work now.

Comment: @glennjackman your answer was the correct one, feel free to post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as suggested:

The problem was that this **bash** script was being invoked with **sh**: on many Linux systems, sh is dash not bash. [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) is a bash feature.

Ideally, add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script, give it execute permissions and invoke it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `find /home/jhvisser/bin/Streamripper_rips -name '*.aac' -mtime -1 -delete`?

Comment: I simplified the script. The script actually creates a lists, combines them all in ffmpeg, and then removes the old files.

Comment: @Fogest Might have helped to know that... Just out of curiosity, what parameters are you invoking ffmpeg with?

Answer (score 1):

I have no permission to post comments, so I had to post this as an answer:

Try to escape the \, replace `s/|/\n/g` with `s/|/\\n/g`.

Comment: @n.st: i think he wants to do some other stuff on the files, the rm was just an example, but even then he can use -exec